# Lilypond - Contemporary Glissando to hidden final note

Tags: lilypond, glissando

I'm trying to typeset a glissando with a known but hidden final note in lilypond 2.19.82. It's called "contemporary glissando" in the manual: [Glissando Manual](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-as-lines#glissando)

I've posted an example on http://www.lilybin.com/jqm370/1 (latest version is 2.19.55 there). The problem is the bars after the glissando. The timing is not correct anymore. What am I missing here?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to turn the cadenza off earlier,

so change lines 22-24 from:

```
  c4\glissando \hideNotes c,,4 \unHideNotes

  \cadenzaOff
```

to:

```
  c4\glissando \hideNotes \cadenzaOff c,,4 \unHideNotes
```

This will give you something like this:

[image: Contemporary Glissando]

Comment: note that now, you won't need that forced bar line on line 26

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is not right; the spacing is incorrect, and it will not align properly if you have other instruments in parallel staves.

This is because the cadenza makes the 3/4 bar have an extra crotched (invisible or not)

What you want is a (/an invisible) grace note at the end of the bar.

So instead replace lines 20-26 with:

```
\afterGrace c4 \glissando { \hideNotes c,,8 \unHideNotes }
```

[image: grace note]